# Creating text file with given content entered in richtextbox but it shrinks all text

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, textbox

I am trying to create a simple win application(C#, VS 2010) which creates a text file(at the location where the executable is) with the given filename(provided in a textbox) and content provided in a richtextbox. The code is like:

```
string executableLocation = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
String path = System.IO.Path.Combine(executableLocation, tbtextname.Text + ".txt");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@path, richTextBox1.Text);
richTextBox1.Clear();
tbtextname.Clear();
```

But it is mixing up everything like if i want to save text:

> my
>
> name
>
> is
>
> superman

then it will give text file content in the format like: `mynameissuperman`. How do I get the text in the format it is entered? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to do something like this

```
richTextBox1.SaveFile("Test.txt or your file path",RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem!  If you dont provide the stream type it will save it as a .RTF file which has alot of junk in there that if you wanted to pass that information alot to another RT box you could but it sounded like you just wanted the plain text out of there so this will  work.

Comment: Yeah, earlier I tried with `richtextbox.Rtf` but it didn't work like what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

`RichTextBox` has a method called `SaveFile()` which saves the contents as a RTF.

This will save all your text including your formatting.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa335487(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The answer has been solved but my apologies
i meant streamwritter not textwritter

Answer (score -1):

Try using the textwritter class
system.io.textwritter writter = new system.io.textwritter("location where you want to save the file")
writter.write("you content");
writter.close();

Comment: showing error: Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.IO.TextWriter' for **new System.IO.TextWriter(path);**